# Cordova media capture plugin bugs (Nexus 6, Android 6)

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I'm experience four separate bugs with the official cordova media capture plugin on a Nexus 6 phone running Android 6.

Some of these bugs did not occur on the Nexus 6p. So I know there may be some phone specific issues here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Bug 1

- open app at portrait orientation
- then rotate to landscape
- press record, then stop
- notice how video preview is rotated in wrong orientation

### Bug 2

- open app
- change camera facing from rear to front
- notice how you can't click record button now

### Bug 3

- open app at portrait orientation
- press record, then stop
- accept video, and notice video cannot be played in a video player

### Bug 4

- open android Photos app
- notice how videos are not shown in gallery
- restart phone and reopen Photos app to see them

Plugin
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

Demo to replicate bugs
https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-media-capture-example

Comment: cordova-plugin-media-capture is giving me flipped videos -_- 180 deg flipped even on android 6.0.1. when the video is recorded on portrait orientation.

Comment: Which phone? Install the 6.0.1 update and restart your phone. Then open the app with cordova-plugin-media-capture first before any other camera apps. The Android update fixed my issues. Maybe you need to update Cordova too? npm install cordova -g or reinstall the Android plugin cordova platform add android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating to Android 6.0.1

Comment: can you explain the resolution properly?

Comment: seems like there was a bug with the specific version of Android and that device. The OS updates fixed the issue